# Flutter Google Maps Detail Bottom Sheet using DraggableScrollableSheet & SliverAppBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm trying to recreate the functionality of a Google Maps detail bottom sheet using Flutter. I'm using `DraggableScrollableSheet` along with a `CustomScrollView` and `SliverAppbar` (though I'd be happy to use another approach).

This gives me (mostly) the desired effect when scrolling up, though I'm wondering how to also  then achieve the sliver app bar from slowly reducing its height as the user scrolls down, eventually 'hiding' it once minChildSize is 'hit' on the `DraggableScrollableSheet`

Here's my current code (stripped down for simplicity).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controllerDetails;

  Tween<Offset> _tween = Tween(begin: Offset(0, 1), end: Offset(0, 0));

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controllerDetails = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }

  bool _onScrollDetails(Notification notification) {
    return true;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerDetails.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  void _showDetails() async {
    if (_controllerDetails.isDismissed) {
      _controllerDetails.forward();
    } else if (_controllerDetails.isCompleted) {
      _controllerDetails.reverse();
    }
  }

  Widget _buildDetails() {
    return SizedBox.expand(
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: _tween.animate(_controllerDetails),
        child: DraggableScrollableActuator(
          child: NotificationListener(
            onNotification: _onScrollDetails,
            child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
              minChildSize: 0.1,
              initialChildSize: 0.3,
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
                return Container(
                  child: CustomScrollView(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    slivers: <Widget>[
                      SliverAppBar(
                        expandedHeight: 200,
                        pinned: true,
                        floating: true,
                        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                            title: Text('Hello World'),
                            background: Image.network(
                              "https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            )),
                      ),
                      SliverFillRemaining(
                        child: Text(
                            "Once the draggable sheet goes below some value (like 0.6) how can i 'parallax' reduce the expandedHeight of the sliverAppBar, then increasing it again as the user scrolls up..."),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: GestureDetector(
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: AnimatedIcon(
              icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close, progress: _controllerDetails),
          elevation: 5,
          onPressed: _showDetails,
        ),
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildDetails(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas / code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect you are trying to achieve is not usual, so it could be difficult to find an elegant way to do it.

Here is a way to achieve that effect, changing the `expandedHeight` property while scrolling:

```
// in the builder of DraggableScrollableSheet
double factor = scrollController.hasClients ? scrollController.position.viewportDimension / MediaQuery.of(context).size.height : 0;

// then in the SliverAppBar
expandedHeight: 200 * factor,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - works pretty well and its quite elegant I think. Wondering if as a follow up you can tell me how to also NOT show the appbar title until the appbar is actually blended in... in other words have no title, just the parallax image, then as the user scrolls up and the appbar starts to blend into view ONLY then will it also show the title in the app bar.

Comment: That's more complicated, you could wrap the `FlexibleSpaceBar` with `LayoutBuilder`, and check if the `constraints.maxHeight` is less than a value to show the title or not, but that will show the title when the bottom sheet is near the bottom, so you may also need to check if `factor >= 0.5` for example, so the title could be like this: `title: factor >= 0.5 && constraints.maxHeight <= 100 ? Text('Hello World') : null,`. The use of `LayoutBuilder` is expensive, but I don't see another way to do it.